# Распознавание одинаковых элементов в цикле из БД в PHP

Tags: php, база-данных, циклы

Есть таблица `users`, и колонка `name` в ней. Значение `name` во многих записях совпадает. Я хочу пройтись циклом по записям таблицы, но выводить из всех записей с одинаковым `name` только одну. Как сделать такое?

Вот мой код:

```
<?
$us = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users`") or die(mysql_error());
$users_prof = mysql_fetch_array($us);

do{
?>

<?
}while($messages = mysql_fetch_array($mess));
?>
```

Comment: Вопрос не вполне понятен. «много одинаковых полей» – это именно полей, или записей с одинаковыми значениями (какого поля)?

Comment: есть много полей name со значением например Андрей
и мне нужно чтобы если в цикле встречаются два раза значение Андрей то выводить только один раз и продолжить цикл

Comment: тут был удалённый зачем-то правильный ответ про [`SELECT DISTINCT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) от [@Дмитрий](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/185542/%d0%94%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b9) – надеюсь, его восстановят и вы сможете принять тот ответ.

Comment: @Sergiks: Его удалил сам владелец вроде.

Comment: @Leno Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если рассматривать неоптимальный, в отличие от `SELECT DISTINCT`, вариант с PHP, то элементарно: надо сохранять в массиве встреченные уже варианты имени *name*, и при рассмотрении очередной строки, проверять, есть ли это значение уже в массиве. Напр. с помощью [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php).

Answer (score 4):

А зачем в PHP фильтровать? Выбирай сразу уникальные записи с помощью `SELECT DISTINCT`